# Error when trying docker-compose up command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azerothcore

I get the following error when trying the docker-compose up command on a fresh install, I'm installing on a external HDD, not on `C:\`.

[image]

Comment: please include the error as text too in your question

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has to do with your docker daemon service thinking it's installed on `C:`.

**Give this a try:**

[image]

[Source](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-could-i-install-docker-for-windows-on-drive-e-my-ssd-c-is-full/52347/2)